# Is there a smart pointer that is automatically nulled when its target is destroyed in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, qpointer

I've found [QPointer](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qpointer.html).  Are there any others?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm) - the `weak_ptr` has some nice features that make it safe to use, if you are also using `shared_ptr`. You keep a `weak_ptr` reference to an instance that is managed by `shared_ptr` lifetime. When you need to use the underlying instance, convert it to a `shared_ptr` instance using the constructor of the `shared_ptr` class, or the `lock` method. The operation will fail if the underlying instance was deleted. The use is thread safe in the same fashion as the `shared_ptr` class:

```
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(5));
weak_ptr<int> q(p);

// some time later

if(shared_ptr<int> r = q.lock())
{
    // use *r
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't aware that weak_ptr had this behaviour.  I wonder how much I'm paying for the unneeded reference counting behaviour though.

Anyway, your answer was first, I think.  Marking as best.

Answer (score 6):

"boost::weak_ptr" works really well with "boost::shared_ptr" (also available in tr1)