# Shared pointer with observer pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector, tree

I have a class Foo, which has a vector of some large classes. The idea is, that an octal tree will be built recursively out of the elements of the vector, and each OctreeNode will have a pointer to few elements of the vector found in Foo. (In the example, just for simplicity, a node will point to only one element of the vector)

```
class Foo
{
    vector<LargeClass>  mLargeClasses;

    void removeItem(const int index);    //remove an element from the vector at the index
}

class OctreeNode
{
    LargeClass* mLargeClass;
}
```

One can say, "why bother keeping the vector after the tree is built, and store the objects in the tree itself". True, let's just say, I need to keep vector parallel to the built tree as well.

While the above concept works, I have issues when elements got removed from the underlying vector. In such case, some Octree nodes end up with dangling pointers.

My solution #1:
If *removeItem* function is called, then before it removes the vector element, it first recursively traverse the octal tree, and make all *mLargeClass* pointer a nullptr which happen to point to that particular vector element. It's ok to have nullptr in the nodes, as I check each time against nullptr, when I access them anyway.

My solution #2:
Have the vector store *shared_ptrs*, and have the OctreeNode store a *weak_ptr*. I am not fan of this, as each time I access a *weak_ptr* in the tree, it gets converted to a *shared_ptr* in the background with all the atomic counter increases. I am not expert on performance testing, but I have a feeling, that it is slower than a simple pointer access with if condition.

Does anybody know any better solutions?

I think the most elegant would be:
To have smart pointer which behaves like a *shared_pointer*, counts, how many other pointer refers to it, keep a record of them, and in case it gets destroyed, it automatically nulls out all other "observer" pointers which refer to it?

Comment: Do you need to use `std::vector`? Are you iterating over it? Is cache locality useful for your application? Other containers may have more favorable invalidation rules. Naive use of `std::shared_ptr` may already reduce cache locality.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, I do iterate through often, so I rely on cache locality.

Comment: Any insertion or removal from the vector potentially invalidates **all** pointers to its elements, so solution #1 won't really work.

Comment: @n.m. Ok, I see now. In that case, I would need to store unique_ptrs in that vector to avoid such case. That would also express that Foo class is the solely owner of the LargeClass vector, and it is responsible to delete it.

Comment: If the order of elements is not important, you can implement solution #1 by swapping the removed element with the last element in the vector and then popping the back off. Then update all nodes that pointed to the erased element with `nullptr` and update all nodes that pointed to the last element so they point to it's new location in the vector.

Comment: @Avithohol If you rely on cache locality, using pointers will likely ruin it.

Comment: There are 2 hard problems in computer science.  Naming things, cache invalidation and off by one errors.  Your OctTreeNode is a cache, and you are having problems with invalidation.  Consider not having a cache.  Unless that cache is highly, highly important, simply finding your node again *could* be faster than the overhead caused by making cache invalidation work.  Regardless, your problem is this cache, and *why* the cache is important to *how* the cache should work.  Explain *why*.

Comment: I think there is a problem. Adding items to the vector can invalidate pointers to them. How often is the tree going to be modified (items added, removed)?

Comment: @Yakk Understand. Why *cache* is important: In the example, I talk about one Octree, but there are many other trees point the same underlying vector elements. Also there are other "users" who iterate the vector as well.

Comment: thanks, noted before by @n.m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the field, and the purpose is somewhat different, i think i will give a try for the handle system described in this port:
[Simple, efficient weak pointer that is set to NULL when target memory is deallocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876150/simple-efficient-weak-pointer-that-is-set-to-null-when-target-memory-is-dealloc)
If I fail, I will revert back to the shared_ptr/weak_ptr duo. Described in the same post.